Determining reachable vertices in 2D from the point of view of an agent with non-negligible size
I want some help/guidance. Suppose I have a character in a 2D world that has no size. That is, the character is a point mass. In this case I can arrive at a vertex of a polygon. Let's assume that all polygons are convex for the time being and if my question makes sense then we can relax that assumption. From this vertex the character can easily survey the world to see which vertices are reachable from its current position. The only operation I have to carry out is a line-of-sight calculation from that vertex of the polygon.
Suppose that now this character is a disk. I understand that I have to carry out further calculations to see if it can fit through a gap to reach a vertex. But there are so many further problems. What does it mean for the character to "arrive" at a vertex? If I cast three rays from the character (one from the centre to the target, then two from the "edges" of the disk to... where?) to try and determine whether a vertex is reachable, where do my rays end?
I am sure this problem has been dealt with in computer graphics, but I do not know what to ask google to be honest.
From doing some sketches I think I have a very weak idea. I was thinking of generating a cone by extrapolating edges of polygons then "fitting" the character in this cone. This allows reachability to adjacent vertices of a polygon and vertices that I would class as reachable. But as per my questions above I do not know where to "end" these ray calculations.
This problem must have been solved before.

It's not clear to me what you mean by "visible". Usually we use this term with reference/analogy to light rays, which always move from a point to a point — the size of the body attached to the eye/camera does not factor into the consideration of visibility. It sounds like you might mean "reachability", as in "can I slide this polygon until part of it makes contact with this point, without any part contacting any obstacle along the way?" — is that accurate? If that's the case, you might want to research "shape casts" or "swept/continuous collision detection" for techniques to answer this query.

Or, another interpretation could be that you're modelling this agent as a broad area light source, and want to know whether / to what extent points in its surroundings are directly lit by rays emanating from all parts of its surface? A little bit of context about what you're using this for in your game, what gameplay application it's supporting, could help remove any ambiguity and focus answers on techniques best suited to your use case.

Reachable is what I meant! Sorry. I will update my post.
